# iOS 10 - NavigationController, view not being hide completely on dismiss

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, ios10

I'm developing an iOS 10 app using NavigationController and Storyboards. I'm having a difficult time to figure out whats going on with a strange - as I'm calling it - bug:

- When I navigate to a new ViewController, it show's nicely, but when the app unwind a segue, the top view controller doesn't go all the way to the right, instead, it left's about 50 points on screen, and then suddenly it goes away...

I'm putting a image that illustrates what I'm talking about...

PS: both ViewControllers uses UIImageView as background...

Thanks a lot!

[image: App illustration]

Comment: Are you running on a device or in the Simulator? Sometimes the Simulator will lag a bit on transitions, esp. when the pixel density of the sim is not 1:1 with your display.

Comment: I've tried both simulator and device...

Comment: You're saying when you tap the Back button, the top view slides and then disappears completely when it's about 50 pixels from the right edge? My first guess is you're doing something wrong in either the popped view's will/didDisappear methods, or the top view's will/didAppear methods. Check the log for any messages that pop up, and maybe inspect the top view's `frame` property to see if it got positioned offscreen. Also check it's `superview` property to verify it hasn't been removed from the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code where you are setting the fame for the view(s). It could possibly be an offset that is being added. Though, you do mention that it does go away suddenly,  so it could be something else.

Comment: Does it behave this way on a device or the simulator? Did you try testing it with a different device? It could be the device or simulator not fast enough and so it takes it a while to redraw. Since you are using the default segues, it will be very hard for you to make such a trivial mistake that would cause the behavior you are getting.